# Find the secondlowest date of purchase SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dataset as:

```
 CustomerID    date
 1             01/01/18
 1             02/01/18
 1             05/12/18
 2             03/03/18
 2             07/11/18
 2             05/12/18
```

I want to find the first and second purchase date group by customer:

```
  CustomerID    1st      2nd
  1             1/1/18   2/1/18
  2             3/3/18   7/11/18
```

How can I use sql to do it? For the first purchase, I just use:

```
 SELECT CustomerID, min(date) as 1st FROM table group by 1
```

but I do not know how to do with the second date of purchase

Comment: Your expected output does not match the actual data.  `7/11/18` can't be the second of three values, because it is the last one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here followed by a pivot:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CustomerID, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY date) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    CustomerID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN date END) "first",
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN date END) "second"
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
GROUP BY
    CustomerID;
```

### Demo

Comment: can it work with the second last date of purchase? Because number of records of userid are different (20 records vs 10 records) How can I put the condition: rn = 19 and rn = 9 as the second last date

Comment: I don't know what you are asking exactly, because I can't see your data.  If you want something other than the first and second earliest by date, then just edit my answer and select row number 9 and 19.  It should still work.

Comment: I mean do you know how to reverse the order from row_number() , so the last date 's rn would be 1 and the second last date would be 2

Comment: Yes, use this: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY date DESC)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method of doing this without subqueries:

```
select CustomerID, min(date) as date_1,
       ( array_agg(date order by date) )[2] as date_2
from t
group by CustomerID;
```